# Plotting with basemap a seamless shapefile at its longitudinal end

Tags: python-3.x, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using a shapefile of continents (Continents-Polygon) found at http://techcenter.jefferson.kctcs.edu/data/ to plot an Antarctica coastline. The shapefile goes from 180ºW to 180ºE, meaning the polygon ends and starts somewhere in the Pacific Ocean. When I plot this shapefile centered in the Pacific Ocean, the result is a coastline that starts at 180ºW, leaving the western part of it without any coastline, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

shapefile = 'continent'
lat = np.arange(-90,-55,2.5)
lon = np.arange(-260,20,2.5)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)

fig=plt.figure(dpi=200)
m=Basemap(projection='cyl',resolution='i',llcrnrlon=np.nanmin(lon),llcrnrlat=np.nanmin(lat),\
          urcrnrlon=np.nanmax(lon),urcrnrlat=np.nanmax(lat))

xi, yi = m(X,Y)
m.readshapefile(shapefile, 'continent',color='k',linewidth=0.6)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80,-40,10),labels=[True,False,False,True],color='0.55',fontsize=6)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-260,20,20),labels=[True,False,False,True],color='0.55',fontsize=6
plt.show()
```

[image: Antarctica]

Any ideas on how to avoid this from happening?

I'm not using basemap's `drawcoastlines` because it includes some parts of sea ice that I do not want in my plot, and I don't know anything about QGIS so that's not really a first choice for me.

Edit: Using another projection such as Polar Stereographic makes appear a line on the plot which I assume is the beginning/end of the shapefile (the straight line at 180º from 90ºS to the coastline). Here's an example of what happens, with the same code as above, but using `spstere` projection:

```
fig=plt.figure(dpi=200)

m=Basemap(projection='spstere',boundinglat=-60,lon_0=90,resolution='l')
xi, yi = m(X,Y)
m.readshapefile(shapefile, 'continent',color='k',linewidth=0.6)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80,-40,10),labels=[True,False,False,True],color='0.55',fontsize=6)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,200,20),labels=[True,False,False,True],color='0.55',fontsize=6)
```

Output:

[image: Stereographic Projection]

Comment: Maybe it works better if you use a projection that is more suitable for plotting data around the south pole, like south-polar stereographic (`spstere`)?

Comment: @j08lue thank you for your input. Using any kind of polar projection, although it shows the entire coastline, produces a line which I assume is the beginning/end of the shapefile. I edited the post to show what happens.